# Python encoding error? UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, encoding, aws-cloudformation, user-data

I have an AWS autoscale instance.
On the AMI for that instance, I have a file `myfile.py` that contains the following string:

```
X5ZŒ
```

In my AWS Cloudformation, LaunchConfiguration, I have UserData that executes the following python instruction when the instance is spun up. It simply reads `myfile.py` and attempts to replace all occurrences of the regexp "X\dZ" with "XYZ":

```
myString = "XYZ".join(re.compile('X\d\Z').split(open("myfile.py", "r").read()))
```

That produces this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Okay. I understand that the character `Œ` is causing trouble because it is non-ASCII. But when I manually run the same statement from the python shell, it works fine without throwing any exception.

How can I force the script that is run by AWS LaunchConfig's UserData to have the same behavior as when I run it manually myself? What encoding should I set and how should I set it?

Comment: Are you using `from __future__ import unicode_literals` in that module?

Comment: Which version of Python?

Comment: @cdarke: almost certainly Python 2, since this involves implicit decoding using ASCII.

Comment: Can you please confirm that you are using string literals for the join string and the regular expression? What does `print repr('XYZ')` produce *from within the same module that throws the error*?

Answer (score 1):

Your file is encoded, that means it represents unicode in a defined way. 
You use some literal strings (e.g. `XYZ`), which shall be used to in oprations together with the file content. These literal strings are encoded just like the file, in which this code is defined.

Python tries to coerce both into the same to be able to operate on it. It is best, if you convert both into unicode. For the string literals, just prepend a `u`, like so: `u"XYZ"`. For the file you have to tell python the encoding, if you don't, it by default assumes `ascii`. Try:

```
 myString = u"XYZ".join(re.compile(u'X\d\Z').split(
     open("myfile.py", "r").read().decode('utf-8')))
```

in this version I used `utf-8`, which has some probability of being right. If you know it being different, you'd have to substitute it for the [right one](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) (your editor in which you saved the file can probably tell you).

EDIT: I removed the part about console and environment settings, which don't apply,  as @Martijn mentioned. He's also right about, that this error is only reproducible if your string literals *are* already implicitly unicode (`from __future__ import unicode_literals`) - in this case there's no need to prepend the string literals with a `u`.

Comment: At issue is mixing Unicode and byte strings. The OP has not shown a full traceback nor have they confirmed if any of the strings are actually unicode. There doesn't appear to be any console interaction (no printing and no reading) involved.

Comment: the part about console interaction is where OP says "manually run the same statement from the python shell, it works fine without throwing any exception."

Comment: @Martijn, I edited my answer to better reflect the issue with string literals, thanks

Comment: The environment settings only affect stdin/stdout/stderr codecs. The string literals are entirely composed of ASCII characters, and `myfile.py` is not going to be decoded implicitly either. So the only thing left is that the join string or the regular expression literals are Unicode strings, and without `u` prefixes that means `from __future__ import unicode_literals` was applied. Or the sample given is not the actual code.

Comment: @Martijn - I agree, and I'm also not sure whether this question/answer pairt adds anything which isn't handled by one of the myriad of other `UnicodeError` questions - would you agree that it's duplicate? (I can also delete my answer)

Comment: It is currently *unclear*; I can't pigeonhole it as a dupe without more context. I'll close it as such.